# SQL CONVERT string to date issue

Tags: sql, dashdb

I have a column with string values like this `05.2015`.

I need to get a DATE value out in the format that the first 2 chars are the month and the day is always the 1st...

so in this example it would be 01/05/2015 ... or 2015-05-01 ..depending on the db.

I tried

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),"String_Date_column",0) from TABLE;
```

but I am getting this error:

> "No authorized routine named "CONVERT" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.. SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, DRIVER=3.69.56 ".

I am running on dashDB.

Comment: It looks like you need to consult the [Datetime scalar functions documentation](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0011043.html?view=kc#r0011043__t11043-5) and ponder using `TO_DATE`.

Comment: Thank you. I found the answer in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TO_DATE (CD."Application_Creation_Period",'mm.yyyy')
```

works just fine. I needed to add `CASE` because the column also holds one char values of "#". So the full answer would be:

```
select case
       when "string_date_column" = '#' then null
       else TO_DATE ("string_date_column",'mm.yyyy')
end as "new date" from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT cast(substring(String_Date_column,4,4)+substring(String_Date_column,1,2)+'01' as date)
```

Comment: I tried this with `sql server`, on `dashDB` it will be `SUBSTR` instead of `substring`

Comment: I keep getting this error:"A value with data type "SYSIBM.DECFLOAT" cannot be CAST to type "SYSIBM.DATE".. SQLCODE=-461, SQLSTATE=42846, DRIVER=3.69.56
" but perharps that's becasue that column also hold values which equal to "#".... anyway. I found another way to get thi done... will post as answer